# Add new properties to file details in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file

I'm trying to add a few custom properties to a file object using PowerShell.

[image]

```
$A = Get-ChildItem C:\TEMP\test.zip
$A | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Status -NotePropertyValue Done
```

I tried the above script but it doesn't show up in the 'details' tab.

Comment: Use `Set-ItemProperty`. The file object has fixed properties. You can amend (some) properties, but not add one.

Comment: @Scepticalist so there is no way to add custom property?

Comment: all of the _extended_ metadata that windows shows is provided by various extensions to file explorer. if you want to add some ... you need to write your own  extension, OR install an app that adds an extension with a property you can use.

Comment: @wonderfulworldwithcharity, [dsofile.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/dsofile.dll-allow-edit-document-property) might provide the functionality you are seeking.  For more info, [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692828(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).  Keep in mind, if you attempt to add, modify, or remove properties on a digitally code-signed file, you will effectively render the digital signature invalid, until you re-sign the file after modifying it.